# Remove div class post nocolsidepost - wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My wordpress theme (Anglepane) is creating a second (unwanted) post at the bottom of my page.

I have used Firefox page inspector and isolated the problem with the div tag "nocolsidepost", and I have gone through the 20+ theme files (css etc) and deleted this tag whereever I find it, but the second posts still remain!! - I can delete it on the fly with Firefox page inspector, but not in the actual code

Could anyone please explain how to solve this

Website is http://historyofliverpool.com and the section I want to remove it the bottom block with the previous / next links on it

Comment: It'll be in a php template. Specifically, one of the following: `front-page.php`, `home.php`, `index.php`, or `footer.php`.

Comment: I still cannot solve it. 
I've looked in all of those files. I have tried deleting elements of the code, but nothing is removing the duplicated bottom pst section. I would really appreciate any help.

There is no support on the themes website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of the code in the theme but it can be in multiple parts of the code.

[TwentyThirteen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentythirteen) and [TwentyFourteen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen) themes (the ones bundled with Wordpress) use a separate function to show the pagination or the Prev/Next buttons. If your theme has this function (usually in `function.php` file) you will have to search for it and delete/modify all the lines that print something. For example, here is the function from TwentyThirteen theme:

```
function twentythirteen_paging_nav() {
global $wp_query;

// Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages < 2 )
    return;
?>
<nav class="navigation paging-navigation" role="navigation">
    <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Posts navigation', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h1>
    <div class="nav-links">

        <?php if ( get_next_posts_link() ) : ?>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) : ?>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- .nav-links -->
</nav><!-- .navigation -->
<?php
}
```

On the other side, the theme can easily implement the corresponding code directly in the `archive.php`, `index.php` and other `category.php`/`tag.php` files. It is similar to the function used above, the only difference is the function wrapper (the first is a function, the second not).

Or, simpler (but less proper) way to achieve this is to add a `display:none;` to the element above. But, to achieve this, you will have to find the code that generates it, to add there an id, and in the CSS use the id like this:

```
#your-id-here{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I appreciete your answer here. I understand the theory of what you're saying, but my I am a self-taught 'trial and error' novice! Could I email you my wordpress login details for you to take a look? I have wasted hours today on this

Comment: You should hire a developer. I'm sure @Nomce would be happy to do a quick freelance job.

Comment: How can I pay someone to fix this for me?

Comment: I will fix it for free this time if you want, just mail me the theme (or the login details, but I advise you not to mail me the login), asap you will have it.

Comment: I have just emailed a link to my dropbox with the theme using the form at nomce.me